# Value of array element changes itself during loop in c language

Tags: c, arrays, loops, for-loop, nested-loops

I have written some simple code in C. The problem is that the element value is changing during the loop, even though there is no such command. All the elements calculated in the first loop become zero after the loop ends. But elements calculated in the 2nd or higher numbered loop show correct values, they don't become zero (obviously). So why did those elements become zero? Where is the mistake?

I have printed the value of `u(1,0)` every time.

```
#include <stdio.h>      /* Standard Library of Input and Output */
#include <complex.h>    /* Standard Library of Complex Numbers */
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define pi 3.141592

int main() {
    // Declaration variables
    // Integers
    int N = 2, Nx = N, Ny = N, i, j; // IMPORTANT GIVE N-1 FOR N
    double x[Nx], y[Ny], lengthX = 1.0, lengthY = 1.0;
    double complex u[Nx][Ny];   

    // FOR X DIRECTION
    for (i = 0; i <= Nx; i++) {
        x[i] = (double)i / (Nx + 1) * lengthX;
        //printf("x coordi is %.15f \n", x[i]);
    }

    // FOR Y DIRECTION
    for (j = 0; j <= Ny; j++) {
        y[j] = (double)j / (Ny + 1) * lengthY;
        //printf("x coordi is %.15f \n", x[i]);
    }

    for (j = 0; j <= Ny; j++) {
        for (i = 0; i <= Nx; i++) {
            printf("x coordi is %.15f \n", x[i]);
            u[i][j] = sin(2.0 * pi * x[i]) * cos(2.0 * pi * y[j]);
            //  x[i] = (double)i / (Nx + 1) * lengthX;
            printf("u is (i,j) = (%i,%i)\t%.15f\t%f\t%f\n", i, j, u[i][j], x[i], y[j]); //correct
            printf("u is (i,j) = (%i,%i)\t element u[1][0] is %.15f \n\n\n", i, j, u[1][0]); 
        }
        printf("\n\n\n End of inside loop (i,j)=(%i,%i)  u(1,0) is \t%.15f \n", i, j, u[1][0]); 
    }
    printf("\n\n u is %i\t%i\t%.15f \n\n", i, j, u[1][0]); 

    printf("\n\n\n\n Why u(1,0) value become zero in the last loop ???????\n");
printf("\n\n\n\n Not only u(1,0) value become zero, but all u(:,0) in the last loop became zero !\n");
    //
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i=0; i<=Nx` => `i=0; i<Nx` else your indices are outside your array or write in the next row

Comment: `for ( j=0; j<=Ny; j++ )` is wrong, you can only index the array to `Ny-1`.

Comment: MANY MANY THANKS Jean-François Fabre AND  Weather Vane

Comment: This all happens because I make codes in FORTRAN !

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question `x[0]` and `y[0]` are zeros and all other indexes are ok. So in your code, there are some bugs.
1. `for ( j=0; j<=Ny; j++ )` and `for ( i=0; i<=Nx; i++ )` you are accessing memory that do not allocated for you program and could be read-only, you could get an error  SEGFAULT.
2. `x[i]=(double)i/(Nx+1)*lengthX;` you start your calculation when j and i are initialized to zero and that why you get zero at first index.

```
for ( i=1; i<=Nx; i++ ) {
        x[i-1]=(double)i/(Nx+1)*lengthX;
        //printf("x coordi is %.15f \n", x[i]);
}

// FOR Y DIRECTION

for ( j=1; j<=Ny; j++ ) 
{
        y[j-1]=(double)j/(Ny+1)*lengthY;
        //printf("x coordi is %.15f \n", x[i]);
}
```

Comment: THANKS YOUR BRIEF EXPLANATION.

Answer (score 0):

Array is overflow its range.Just as above floor,you should correct the loop:
replace `for ( i=0; i<=Nx; i++ )` with `for(i = 0; i < Nx; i++)`,cause there's only `Nx` elements,but you set one more

Comment: THANK YOU Ethan2048